# Caching of queries...how to clear?

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I'm using Linq to query an Entity Framework SQL database.

Here's my code:

```
var found = this.keys.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Key.ToLowerInvariant() == key.ToLowerInvariant());
```

I received the following error:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String
>   ToLowerInvariant()' method, and this method cannot be translated into
>   a store expression.

I promptly changed it to:

```
var found = this.keys.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Key.ToLower() == key.ToLower());
```

However, I received the same error.  I tested it with the following:

```
var found = this.keys.FirstOrDefault();
```

I still receive the exact same error. Is this somehow being cached or something?  Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm so confuse about the variable key.ToLower() ?? Is it different from the this.key ????

Comment: Sorry! Yes, it's different. This method takes a key parameter and tries to retrieve the values from the DB.  To do this it converts it to lower case. (I understand it makes sense to define a variable instead, but I didn't think it was relevant for this example.)

Comment: Are you sure you saved the change and are rebuilding the project between tests?

Comment: Yes, I have run the Clean command, and manually cleaned the bin directories.  I have tried inserting code to verify it's the new version and it is.

Comment: Sorry everyone I made a mistake. It was referencing an IEnumerable in a previous method that did call ToLowerInvariant(). Thanks everyone for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Queries against EF are translated to SQL and as so, it tries to convert your query without success because EF can't convert many expressions that LINQ to objects can.
You can find more about it in msdn.

Comment: I understand that completely, but the issue isn't that it can't translate the ToLowerInvariant() method, but that even once I changed it to ToLower() (which is valid), and then simply to just FirstOrDefault(), it is somehow caching the previous expression.